# IOS Random behavior on In App Purchases - Invalid products, App exits

Tags: c#, ios, in-app-purchase, xamarin

OK, I know the sandbox is junk and doesn't work well.  But I'm going nuts trying to get the app to run ONCE through correctly with an In App Purchase.  I did all the setup in Connect, creating two IDs.

If I do a Clean, and a build all  (Critical steps on EVERY run)
And remove the App from the device (Also, critical on EVERY run)

THEN I will get back 2 valid products from the request to get Products back from a product list.

C# / Xamarin Studio btw.

I have this code:

```
    public bool BuyPurchase (SKProduct Product)
    {
        SKPayment payment = SKPayment.PaymentWithProduct (Product); 
        SKPaymentQueue.DefaultQueue.AddPayment (payment);
        return true;
    }
```

And I realize that I can't return the status in this method, but it would be nice if when I stepped over the line above 'return true;' it stepped to that line instead of having the APP EXIT.

And if I run the app again, I can see the 2 items in the list (same valid IDs) but this time they come back as Invalid.  Wipe and clean and reinstall, and they come back good.  I've verified the parameters to the function.

Questions:
    1. what could I be doing wrong?
    2. Is In App Purchase REALLY this fragile?   I've not seen any issues with real apps not being able to request an in app purchase list more than once.
    3. I know it doesn't run in the simulator because someone was lazy and didn't implement it, but I'm running on the an actual iPhone  (iOS 5.1.1 - not that it should matter much as in App Purchases work fine on my iOS 5.1.1 phone)  3GS phone too.   [Before anyone says upgrade to iOS 7.X and test it there, it has to work on 5.x when I release - unless Apple dropped support for in App purchases for 5.x iOS]

Update:

Using the old interface ALSO causes the App to exit (no return from that function)

And 2, you can avoid the build->clean, and just delete the app from the phone to get it to get valid products back from Apple (I set a break point to make sure I wasn't doing something strange and both requests are exactly the same.)

I also verified that using the old interface blows up on the same line:

```
    public void BuyPurchase (string Product)
    {

         SKPayment payment = SKPayment.PaymentWithProduct (Product);    
  BLAMO>>     SKPaymentQueue.DefaultQueue.AddPayment (payment);
    }
```

-C

---

Traderhut Games

Comment: I just realized, iOS 5.X didn't have the interface taking a SKProduct - it used a string right?  I need to call the deprecated version right?

Comment: Assuming the above idea works, does anyone know of an example getting the Apple hosted content after the purchase is made?  C# example would be awesome.